# How do I boot my Samsung laptop from a CD/DVD?

Tags: uefi, bootable-media

I have a Samsung Series 3 laptop and want to boot from an Ubuntu Live CD.  When I press F10 to pull up the BIOS/boot configuration, I don't get an option to boot from the CD.  Similarly, in the BIOS, I can see that the optical drive is present, but under Boot Options I can only select the hard drive as a boot device.

Answer (score 18):

The CD is not offered as a boot option because Secure Boot is enabled.  Before you can boot from a CD, you must do the following:

1. Upon powering on the laptop, press `F10`
2. Select the option to modify the BIOS settings
3. Go to the `Boot Options` screen
4. Set `Secure Boot` to `Disabled`
5. Set BIOS mode to `UEFI and Legacy` or `CSM and UEFI OS`
6. Save settings and reboot
7. When the Samsung screen comes up again, press `F10`
8. Now when you try to select a boot device, the optical drive will be listed

With certain Samsung notebooks (like the 300E) holding F3 during boot will bring up the Boot from Disc option.

Comment: Any idea if its not listing? windows 10 became a problem :-/