# How can I make my laptop boot automatically from the hard drive without having to press F10 each time?

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, boot

I followed the instructions in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/521390) to [How do I boot my Samsung laptop from a CD/DVD?](https://superuser.com/questions/521389/how-do-i-boot-my-samsung-laptop-from-a-cd-dvd)

Once I installed Windows I found that I have to press <kbd>F10</kbd> to select the hard drive every single time to make it boot into Windows. I tried re-enabling Secure Boot but then I am unable to find the hard drive in the bootable devices list.

What should I do?

---

my labtop is sumsang core i3 
i mean that when i wanted to change my windows i can not find cd-rom in the list of F10
i saw the Instructions of this link

[How do I boot my Samsung laptop from a CD/DVD?](https://superuser.com/questions/521389/how-do-i-boot-my-samsung-laptop-from-a-cd-dvd)

i Succeeded to do that and i changed my windows
but then i can not go to windows automatically 
I had to press F10 to select hard drive
and i can go to windows
i want To what it was before so I make secure boot (enabled)
but I can't find hard drive on the list of F10.

maybe i Erred in doing my new windows

If i changed my windows again i can go to windows automatically or not

please i wait your advice and Instructions

Comment: The directions you posted are not clear.  You cannot select both UEFI and Legacy BIOS mode at the sametime, one of those, either or decisions.  Your hdd a MBR or GPT partition hdd?

Comment: is it set to a master/slave with the plastic pins?

Comment: @mehow There are no master/slave headers on hard drives anymore. Since his computer has UEFI I doubt his HDD is PATA.

Comment: Jumpers on SATA drives control things like PM2 and not master/slave.  (http://www.wdc.com/wdproducts/library/other/2579-001037.pdf)  Since SATA is point to point and each interface has a maximum of one drive, master/slave doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Ramhound There is no such thing as a master/slave concept in the SATA standard. Each device has it's own channel and cable. The headers on newer drives are for speed compatibility and sometimes TTL.

Comment: If you need to update your question, please use the [edit] link under the post - do not create a new question or post your updates as answers.

Answer (score 2):

there are two ways you can get your computer to boot from CD/DVD

**1: Change the first boot device from BIOS**

1. Turn on the PC
2. Press <kbd>F2</kbd> at the Samsung Logo

   > Make sure you don't change anything else unless you know what you are doing
3. You would see BIOS Setup Utitlity
4. Navigate to Boot
5. Go to Boot Device Priority and press enter
6. You would see a list of Bootable Devices
7. Using <kbd>F5</kbd>/<kbd>F6</kbd> to change values, makeCD/DVD the first boot device
8. Press enter and <kbd>F10</kbd> to save and exit

You should be able to boot the computer using CD/DVD now

> Make sure you don't change anything else unless you know what you are doing

**2: Access one time boot menu**

Try <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>F4</kbd> to access One Time Boot menu in samsung computers