# Boot Windows without pressing F10

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive

I have a Samsung Core i3 laptop. When I wanted to change my Windows I could not find the CD-ROM in the list that you get when you press <kbd>F10</kbd>. I saw the Instructions from this question:

[How do I boot my Samsung laptop from a CD/DVD?](https://superuser.com/questions/521389/how-do-i-boot-my-samsung-laptop-from-a-cd-dvd)

I succeeded to do that and I changed my Windows, but now I can't boot Windows automatically – I have to press <kbd>F10</kbd> to select my hard drive.

I enabled Secure Boot, but I can't find the hard drive on the <kbd>F10</kbd> list. What can I do to get it back and boot Windows automatically?